# Objective C Properties

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I tried searching for this issue, but can't seem to find out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my controller header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BabyLearnViewController : UIViewController {
    UIButton *btnImage;
    MediaManager* myMediaManager;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *btnImage;
@property (retain) MediaManager* myMediaManager;

- (IBAction)setNewImage;

@end
```

Here is my controller class:

```
#import "BabyLearnViewController.h"
#import "MediaManager.h";

@implementation BabyLearnViewController

@synthesize btnImage;
@synthesize myMediaManager;
```

I am getting the errors:

```
error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'MediaManager'
error: no declaration of property 'myMediaManager' found in the interface
```

Any ideas?  Usually the 1st error comes up if you have a cylical reference.  'MediaManager' doesn't reference anything else.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you have no mentions of MediaManager class at the moment it is used in header file compiler can't figure out what "MediaManager" is and issues an error. Declare that class using forward declaration in your header file to let compiler know that MediaManager is actually a class:

```
@class MediaManager;
@interface BabyLearnViewController : UIViewController {
   ...
```

P.S. As an alternative you can import MediaManager.h in your header, but using forward declaration is preferred.

Comment: Why is using a forward declaration preferred?

Comment: @Rudy, with forward declaration you won't run into circular dependencies between headers + less headers may improve compile time a bit

Answer (score 2):

Place `#import "MediaManager.h"`
 this in header file of BabyLearnViewController

Answer (score 1):

try add @class MediaManager; before @interface